# How expensive it is to create a new UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have been told that UIWebView are big and expensive (memory and computationally) to create and retain. Is this true? and how expensive are they?

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on what you're loading in them.

The Instruments application's [memory and CPU monitors](http://blog.zincroe.com/2009/04/how-to-check-iphone-texture-memory-usage-with-instruments/) will let you test and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use one UIWebView in my app (with the singleton pattern), and change its content at each displaying.

I thought that it would take a lot of memory, but in comparison to allocate a few UIImages for instance, it is really nothing (as far as Instruments could tell me).